# ¿como recargar pagina cuando se rote un dispositivo?

Tags: javascript

Necesito que cuando rote un dispositvo en la direccion que sea (de portrait a landscape, o de landscape a portrait) se recargue la web. Sé como recargar la pagina [location.reaload()] pero no sé como detectar cuando se rota un dispositivo, para aplicar el recargado. Quiero que se recargue la web solo cuando detecte una rotacion. Si una persona ingresa en portrait o landscape, sin rotar su movil o tablet, que no se recargue.

Comment: Que has intentado?

Answer (score 1):

Se puede detectar el modo de la orientación utilizando Jquery Mobile con orientationchange.

```js
 
 /* Función para actualizar página
  function actualizar() {
      location.reload(true);
  }
 */

$( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
      alert( "Este dispositivo está en modo " + event.orientation);
      /*Llamar a la función
      actualizar();
      */
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```